# Not able to compile GTK files

Tags: ubuntu, path, c, gcc, gtk

I installed gtk manually through source and everything was correct but when I try to run my gtk C files. It gives an error saying that the <gtk/gtk.h> are not found.

So far I understood that it's because of my PATH because when I change the line:`#include <gtk/gtk.h> to #include <gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h>` the error subsides but again the next include file i.e glib.h gives error because it is outside of the gtk-4.0 directory.

I have a CPPFLAG set to $HOME/usr/include/
but it does not include the sub-directories.

What should I do?

```
arif@me:~/Desktop/Programs/GTK$ gcc main.c
```

`main.c:1:10: fatal error: gtk/gtk.h: No such file or directory 1 | #include <gtk/gtk.h> |          ^~~~~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

```
arif@me:~/Desktop/Programs/GTK$ gcc -I $HOME/usr/include/gtk-4.0 main.c
```

`In file included from /home/arif/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/gtk.h:30, from main.c:1: /home/arif/usr/include/gtk-4.0/gtk/css/gtkcss.h:30:10: fatal error: glib.h: No such file or directory 30 | #include <glib.h> |          ^~~~~~~~ compilation terminated.`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep using simply `#include <gtk/gtk.h>` in your source file and compile your test program like this:

```
cc main.c -o test_program `pkg-config --cflags --libs gtk4`
```

This assumes that you have the development packages installed -- if not you should do something like `apt-get install libgtk-4-dev` before.